# Has any appeal trying to revert a bad judge decisions been successful?

Tags: mma, ufc

I sometimes see some UFC or other MMA fighter and their team appealing what is in as a bad judge decisions, e.g. https://www.mmafighting.com/2020/5/17/21261398/dana-white-believes-edson-barboza-deserved-to-win-agrees-with-claudia-gadelha-decision ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200524214442/https://www.mmafighting.com/2020/5/17/21261398/dana-white-believes-edson-barboza-deserved-to-win-agrees-with-claudia-gadelha-decision)).

Has any of these appeals trying to revert a bad judge decisions been successful? (assuming there is no obvious mathematical scoring errors, some failed drug test or some other rule violation from the opponent: the appeal is solely focus on the quality of the judge decision).

Comment: Partially successful `Fedor vs Maldonado`. And again recently `Cerveny vs Cooper` was "controversial". But I think you know these  Just commented.